# Confusion with select() - stdout never ready for write

Tags: c, unix, select, io

Here is a simple select() loop:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

#define BUFSIZE 999

int main()
{
    int            select_result;
    fd_set         read_fds, write_fds;
    struct timeval timeout = {0, 400000}, timeoutcopy;
    const int max_fd = STDIN_FILENO > STDOUT_FILENO ? STDIN_FILENO :
                                                      STDOUT_FILENO;
    char buffer[BUFSIZE];

    fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK);
    fcntl(STDOUT_FILENO, F_SETFL, fcntl(STDOUT_FILENO, F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK);
    printf("Enter loop\n");
    while(1) {
        FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
        FD_ZERO(&write_fds);
        printf("Loop\n");
        FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &read_fds);
        FD_SET(STDOUT_FILENO, &write_fds);

        timeoutcopy = timeout;
        if ((select_result = select(max_fd, &read_fds, &write_fds, NULL,
                                    &timeoutcopy)) < 0) {
            return select_result;
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &read_fds))
            printf("Stdin ready for read\n");
            fgets(buffer, BUFSIZE, stdin);
            if (strlen(buffer))
                printf("Stdin content: %s\n", buffer);
        if (FD_ISSET(STDOUT_FILENO, &write_fds))
            printf("Stdout ready for write\n");
    }
}
```

It just polls `stdin` and `stdout` with `select()` with timeout of 400000 milliseconds. When `stdin` is ready it tries to read it's content and print it. When `stdout` is ready, it just prints, that it it ready.

And for some reason, after `select()` call `stdin` is never ready, why?

Comment: In copying the code, have you missed braces `{...}` following `if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &read_fds))` ... as written, it will always run the `fgets()` so there will (I think) be no/little chance for characters to be typed to make `stdin` ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `max_fd` should be "the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the three sets, plus 1." according to the select man page. I should rename it so you'll remember to add 1.

Answer (score 0):

max_fd must be incremented by 1. The name is indeed confusing, "nfds" is probably more clear. Please have a look here:

[select man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)